# Flutter Release apk won't run or open on android devices

Tags: android, flutter

I have built a release android apk file, conceived for a size of 7.9 MB.
I manage to install it on my android device, but not to open it because it crashes. 
When i use `flutter run --release` it still does not open and detects no errors.

How can I solve that problem?
Thank you for your help.

Note: I have found several questions close to mine, but they have an error or are not entirely similar to mine. As a consequence the solution given do not work on my case.

Here is some of my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.misteref.mykamus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           useProguard true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you added signin configue to android app ?

Comment: it sounds like your releasebuild does not include all ABIs, so the architecture that your device needs does not exist in the build. Im not a flutter expert though

Comment: @AnkitMahadik yes, all the steps for build release apk is done.

Comment: Can you show us some signin configue of your project so it will be easy to track problem

Comment: @JoachimHaglund i have use this flutter build apk --split-per-abi, it's build 2 apk, none of them work. 1 apk cant install and the last 1 can install but cant open

Comment: @AnkitMahadik what example that i can post here? some code that  i put on build.gradle or what?

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/acdruw/flutter_build_apk_release_only_works_on_arm/

Comment: yes @AdamTheory

Comment: @ankitmahadik i have post it on the question post. you can check on top.

Comment: @ikben i have use it. the app still crash when open in my android device

Answer (score 1):

in app level build.gradle
set `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to false
or use progaurd if you need this two be true

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: where i have to put it in build.gradle?

Comment: buildTypes => release

Comment: i have tried this and cant built. it's give an androidx error

Comment: so add android x support to your project
look at this `https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration`

Comment: try this method:
remove `Proguard` and `proguardFiles` lines and set `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to `false` then build your project and check its work or not?

Comment: it's work when i build and install. but still crash when i open the app on android device or emulator.

Comment: yeah I know what are you saying but try this way and tell if it works

Comment: i have try it. still crash when open the app

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Joachim Haglund's comment

update your gradle file with the following. All the builds will then be included in the aab file. (It's also worth checking what SDKs you have installed/require updating with Android Studio)

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        //add the following
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are these errors? I can't help if you don't provide details. Did  you check you have NDKs installed in android studio?

Comment: i mean errors when i use flutter build apk --split-per-abi , but no errors when i use flutter build apk --release. but still, it can open the app in my android device

Comment: why are you building apk individually instead of using the app bundle function? Are you building from Visual Studio Code or Android Studio, what happens when you build using the other application?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue with alternative resolution where, as described in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783824/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-flag), my flutter app was able to run in release mode by adding the following dependency in my build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

This fix is applicable if you see an error message like

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
```